# AppID not appearing in BundleID while launching app

Tags: ios

I have created an "**App id**"  via **Apple Developer Site** it is created successfully. Now i am trying to add a new app, it do ask for "**Bundle ID**" and when i checked the App id i created is not appearing in that list.

What more surprising is that some of the old "**App id**" i created and used and launched apps through them are also not shown in Bundle ID list.

Any idea what is wrong or what i might be doing wrong?

Comment: maybe name of application, or try to reload page (go to the page from begin), it is not updated when you adding new bundle id.

Comment: i tried loging out n then loging in and Bundle ID don't require app name to be specified to make it bundle id available

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, the reload is just not enough and you have to go to the page from the iTunes Connect again.